# Where is my database and App_Data folder?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mdf, membershipreboot

I have downloaded a project and ran the code and I created an account on my locally running MVC site.

I want to delete the database so that it will build a new one; but I can't seem to locate the database. It is supposed to be in `App_Data`, is it not?  I don't even have an `App_Data` folder in my project. I have already set Windows to Show Hidden Files and Folders.

Where is this database!?

```
<add name="MembershipReboot" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MembershipReboot;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the entire web.config:

https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/master/samples/SingleTenant/SingleTenantWebApp/Web.config

I downloaded the `/samples/SingleTenant` for my own testing of it's functionality.

Ref. https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot

**Edit:** When I put a breakpoint on this line:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
```

The value of `path` is:

> "C:\Users\Dom\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SingleTenant\SingleTenantWebApp\App_Data"

But there is no such folder in my `SingleTenantWebApp` directory.

Comment: From Visual Studio open SQL Server Object Explorer (View menu) and see properties of SQL Server and database.

Comment: It shows SQL Server -> localdb -> Databases -> master, model, msdb, and tempdb.  None of these seem to have any relevant tables, however.

Answer (score 2):

Check following locations:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0

Comment: Thanks for this; however, I don't have any SSDT folder in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ and I do have databases in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0 but none called "MembershipReboot."

Comment: Have you checked in: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\Projects ?

Comment: My path is `C:\Users\Dom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0` and there is no Projects folder therein.  Just various databases like "master.mdf."